# Create web proxy through openvpn

Tags: html, iframe, nginx, proxy, vpn

I have a VPN server installed and I'm connecting to it from my PC with a VPN client to visit a particular website which allows traffic only from particular location. Here is the schema that is now:

```
[PC] ===> [VPN Server] ===> [Website]
```

What I want to do is I want to create a simple HTML page with few iframes and I want each iframe to be pointed to different website through DIFFERENT VPN server. Here is the schema of what I wish to do:

```
[PC] ===> [My Website] ===> [iFrame tag] ====> [VPN Server 1] ====> [Target Website]
[PC] ===> [My Website] ===> [iFrame tag] ====> [VPN Server 2] ====> [Target Website]
[PC] ===> [My Website] ===> [iFrame tag] ====> [VPN Server N] ====> [Target Website]
```

I have created a simple nginx proxy that is listening on port 5001 and passing all traffic to traget website A. Port 5002 passes all traffic to target website B

But that is a simple nginx proxy, I need that proxy to pass all traffic to different websites through different VPN servers. Let's say, when reffering to port 5001, nginx will then refer to IP 1.1.1.1, and that IP will comunicate with website A and then return back the traffic to nginx:

```
[PC] => [MyWebsite] => [iFrame] => [NGINX] => [OpenVPN-Server 1] => [Target Website A]
[PC] => [MyWebsite] => [iFrame] => [NGINX] => [OpenVPN-Server 2] => [Target Website B]
```

I'm lost in those schemas and I have no idea what to do, could anyone give any suggestion on how that kind of solution should be organized? Thank you in advance!